# python scrapy formrequest not giving correct url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to scrap some address data from the Howdens website.  However, to do that I need to enter some form data to find the local depot near a postcode of my choice.

The start url is "https://www.howdens.com/about-us/contact-your-local-depot/"

and the source code is:

```
<form id="addressForm" _lpchecked="1">
        <label for="address">
            Enter your Postcode / Town:
            <i id="searchNearest" class="icon-search depot-search"></i>
            <input name="address" id="address" class="address-input" value="" ""="">
        </label>
        <div id="add_matches" class="noDisplay">
            <strong>Multiple results found for your input address. Please select one and search again:</strong>
            <select id="add_sel" onchange="document.getElementById('address').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"></select>
        </div>
        <p>

        </p>
    </form>
```

The python code I am attempting to use is:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from Howdens.items import HowdensItem

class howdensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "howdens"
    allowed_domains = ["www.howdens.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.howdens.com/about-us/contact-your-local-depot/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formxpath='//*[@id="addressForm"]', formdata={'address':'W3'}, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="sidebar"]'):
            item = HowdensItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('./h2/text()').extract()
            item['address'] = sel.xpath('./p/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

So far, the problems all reside at the FormRequest line.  It returns a url of "https://www.howdens.com/about-us/contact-your-local-depot/?address=W3" instead of submitting the request to the site to return a more detailed url.

any guidance as to where I am going wrong would be greatfully received?

Comment: the post is to `https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php`, it uses latitude and longitude,if I input London -> `https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php?lat=51.5073509&lon=-0.12775829999998223&distance=1000&units=MILES`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you for that Padraic.  May I ask how I would incorporate that in my code.  I tried `yield FormRequest.from_response(response, url="https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php", formxpath='//*[@id="addressForm"]', formdata={'address':'London'}, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)`  . . . . . though that did not seem to work

Comment: I did that in the browser, if you look under the xhr tab in chrome dev tools, you can see what happens.  pretty sure the coordinates are gotten using google maps so replicating would not be totally straight forward. Getting late in the night here but if you don't get a solution overnight I will have a proper look when I get a chance tomorrow

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you for that Padraic.  I struggled to fully replicate how the site gets hold of the longitude and latitude for a postcode - hence, i adjusted my code above to search by longitude and latitude using the https://www.howdens.com/process/searchLocationsNear.php that you pointed me in the direction of.